# UISlider or UISwitch with a stationary mask?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, core-graphics, uislider, uiswitch

I've found a gorgeous switch that I'd like to implement in iOS.  The artist (@jasonlong) has kindly shared his PSD of the components at [365psd.com](http://365psd.com/day/329/), along with a crafty little [javascript](http://preation.blackantmedia.com/switches.html) as a demo.

Now, here's where I get into trouble... The custom UISlider and UISwitch examples I've found seem to rely on a track that's stationary with a movable knob/toggle.  In the switch below, it would require a knob/track to animate behind a mask that also passes through touch events.

I've never been much of an interface coder, but this cute little bugger is just to awesome to leave alone.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image: Metal Slider Switches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest just having the background stationary, and just fade between them?  Sliding the track is probably not going to work so well, as you can still see the green/white around the edge of the knob.

Comment: I think you may be right.  I'll play around with that a little bit and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I haven't attempted your suggestion yet, but I've tried a few other things with unpleasant results.  I created a UISegmentedControl with the knob/tracks as the segment images and it was just awful. I don't know why I thought that would be anything better.  Huge issues with alpha channels, and an inflexible gap between the segments.  I think the next step is to do a UISlider with a stationary track, as you say, with the knob as the only movable component, then fade in the new track upon completion.  Now I need to figure out how to do a fade!

Comment: This worked.  I also had fairly good luck with [UICustomSwitch](http://www.catamount.com/blog/?p=1063)

Comment: EVEN BETTER!!! I found something that looks to be pretty customizable and it's got the roundedness ... https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch